# Simple C Preprocessor substitution

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

So i wrote a simple program to try and get a more fundamental understanding of the `#define` macro and i want to know what the difference between these two programs are and is there any fundamental reason to use the third program? :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 7

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = x * x * x;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints out 343 because 7 * 7 * 7 = 343

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 5+2

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = x * x * x;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints out 27 from order of operations.
EDIT
A way to force the second one to print out 343 we could add brackets so we could do the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x (5+2)

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = x * x * x;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Would there be any reason to do it this instead of the first way?

Comment: It's literally just a string substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro substitution replaces the text *as it is*.

Thus the C compiler *sees* the code

```
i = 7 * 7 * 7;       // when #DEFINE x 7
```

in one case, and the following in another

```
i = 5+2 * 5+2 * 5+2; // when #DEFINE x 5+2
```

(And due to simple arthihmetic precedence the results are trivially different.)

---

To make them equivalent one would need to add parenthesis, such as (preferred, see comment):

```
#define x (5+2)
```

although the following would "suffice" here

```
i = (x) * (x) * (x);
```

Comment: `#define x (5+2)` is the correct way to address this issue.  Macros should always be written this way: every argument should be parenthesized within the expansion and the whole expression should be parenthesized.  Rare exceptions can be tolerated in very special cases well beyond the scope of this question.